# Date Archives' Permalinks under Category folder

Tags: permalinks, archives, rewrite-rules

I have my WP put under

```
/wp
```

and then my-blog (which is an category, with the slug name 'my-blog') is set to access from (via the plugin 'Top level category')

```
/my-blog/
```

everything seems fine, except my date-archives goes directly under the root as

```
/2016/09/
```

which is the default permalink. 
However, I would like those date-archives of above category permalinks as:

```
/my-blog/2016/09/
```

Is it possible to change rewrite rules to work? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats posible by using Custom Structure of the permalinks like below:

```
/%category%/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%/
```

You will also be able to get a monthly archive of the category by going to:

```
/%category%/%year%/%monthnum%/
```

like:

```
www.yoursite.com/my-blog/2016/09/
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd look into [Jesper's answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/239516/98212) first since it seems to be that permalink settings is not set up the way you want it to be.

If you're still having issues, you can add the following to your `.htaccess` file in between the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` tags:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/(.*)$ /my-blog/$1/$2 [R=301,L]
```

This will add the `my-blog` slug if someone were to access `http://example.com/2016/09/`, etc. Your `.htaccess` should looks like the following:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# Custom Rewrite
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/(.*)$ /my-blog/$1/$2 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Interesting! My problem is solved by @JesperNilsson's reply. However this approach is also very helpful for my further customizing. Thank you!!

Comment: @Nath Glad you found your solution. Since you found my answer also helpful, and upvote would be appreciated.

Comment: Jinks I have already upvote your answer, but it did not work, saying I need at least 15 reputations.